# Multiple digital signatures with images in PDF using iTextSharp in C#

Tags: c#, itext, digital-signature

I am trying to add multiple digital signatures (with images of signatures) in a pdf using iTextSharp library. Using the PdfSignatureAppearance.CERTIFIED_FORM_FILLING and PdfSignatureAppearance.NOT_CERTIFIED I am able to add digital signatures without invalidating previous signatures but my requirement is little more complex. Along with the digital signatures, we also need to append the signature image. When Signature image is added to the stamper, the previous signature gets invalidated. Is there a way to achieve this? Please help

In the code below, with the image lines commented, it works. When I remove the comments, image get appended but previous signature gets invalidated

```
 int signatureCount = GetSignatureCount(reader);
            int signatureStartPos = signatureCount * 160 + 20;
            PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.SignatureAppearance;
            appearance.SignatureRenderingMode = PdfSignatureAppearance.RenderingMode.DESCRIPTION;

            //string imagePath = _signatureImagePath;
            //iTextSharp.text.Image signatureFieldImage = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imagePath);
            //appearance.SignatureGraphic = signatureFieldImage;

            //signatureFieldImage.SetAbsolutePosition(signatureStartPos, 50);
            //signatureFieldImage.ScaleAbsolute(90f, 30f);
            //stamper.GetOverContent(1).AddImage(signatureFieldImage);

            appearance.Reason = reason;
            appearance.Location = location;
            if (signatureCount == 0)
                appearance.CertificationLevel = PdfSignatureAppearance.CERTIFIED_FORM_FILLING;
            else
                appearance.CertificationLevel = PdfSignatureAppearance.NOT_CERTIFIED;

            appearance.SetVisibleSignature(new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(signatureStartPos, 10, 140+ signatureStartPos, 60), 1, m_processStage);
```

Comment: Any content that you add invalidates the signature, be it text or images. There's no way to keep the signature valid.

Comment: If we add a form field in the pdf form and fill that with an image may be an option? filling form fields is allowed right?

Comment: Well, there strictly speaking are no image form fields. Usually one uses buttons and changes their appearances. This probably already counts as annotation changing, not merely form filling.